# trying to make snakecase program

Tags: python, snakecase

so i have to make an snakecase program

```
camelcase = input("camelCase: ")

snakecase = camelcase.lower()

for c in camelcase:
    if c.isupper():
        snakecase += "_"
        snakecase += c.lower()
        print(snakecase)
```

with the for im going through each letter, the if is for finding the uppercase right? but im failing on the last part, i dont really understand how to not add the "_" and c.lower() at the end of the word but just replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `+=` you are adding the `_` to the end of the `snakecase` variable. This you do for every uppercase character and then add the character itself. The output should be something like `myteststring_t_s` for `myTestString`.

Instead, build the new string one char by the other.

```
camel_case = 'myTestString'
snake_case = ""

for c in camel_case:
    if c.isupper():
        snake_case += f'_{c.lower()}'
    else:
        snake_case += c

print(snake_case)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): it is more Pythonic and concise:

```
camelcase = input("camelCase: ")
snakecase = ''.join(c if c.lower() == c else '_' + c.lower() for c in camelcase)
print(snakecase)
```